# GridLayout or TableLayout with item over 2 cells

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-gridlayout

I have to do a particular layout that looks like a grid but with one item (in red in my exemple) over 2 cells. An exemple is better than words so that's how the layout should look like :[image]

I was searching around GridLayout and TableLayout but didn't find any clue of how this could be made. If anyone knows if it's possible to do it using such a layout it will help me a lot.

Or at least if no solutions exists using those layouts, could someone guide me with another one?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

[Sample for you problem](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridlayout.php)

add android:layout_span="3" to span 3 columns. For example:

```
<TableRow>
                <Button android:id="@+id/item_id"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="item text" />     
            </TableRow>
```

[Video tutorial for Grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeb9CGSeci8)

[Insert view to GridLayout dynamically, with even width and height](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/09/insert-view-to-gridlayout-dynamically.html)

[Custom GridLayout](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100)

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is not really what I expected, I doesn't want to span columns but to have an item beteween 2 of them.